# Page Layout based on Semantic-UI Grid: cannot remove the gutters

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am creating a web application using `semantic-ui`.  I am trying to create a layout which has a sidebar and main content area.  At first, I thought using grid would be the way to go, except that they cause a few problems:

1. The columns and rows will have extra spacing/gutters between them
2. The only way to "remove" the gutters is to set a column color with something like `<div class="four wide black column">`, but this causes the columns to overlap with other content

So it seems that grid are not the best tool for creating page layouts, although they do provide functionality which makes them useful for page layouts (like defining section sizes; `four wide column`, `ten wide column`, etc)

What is the recommended way to layout web applications using Semantic-UI, such as a simple sidebar and main content columns?

Comment: apparently it doesnt look like you can remove the gutters totally, but you can simply override semantic css and enforce your rules, also while building semantic you can change aq lot of parameters, among them margins and paddings, I didnt check but im pretty sure gutters will be there too. Just set them to 0px. This is the best way of customisation, and it persists easily when updating to the new version.

Comment: for the side menu, use sidebar though :)

Comment: This depends entirely on if you are working with the source, or the compiled version? If you are using the source, create a another grid class that doesn't not honour the margins like `ui grid tight` or something. Then you still have both options.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you override the default margin and padding applied for "grid" and "column" like this,

```
.your-custom-class.grid {
    margin: 0;
}
.your-custom-class.grid .column {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Thus you'll get a grid with no space in between the columns.